# How to preprocess high cardinality categorical features?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, logistic-regression

I have a data file which has features of different mobile devices. One column with categorical data type has 1421 distinct types of values. I am trying to train a logistic regression model along with other data that I have. 
My question is: Will the high cardinality column described above affect the model I am training? If yes, how do I go about preprocessing this column so that it has lower number of distinct values?

Comment: How many data points do you have? There is a high risk of overfitting. Unless you have *many* values per distinct type, you may want to completely ignore the attribute because of this. (*Avoid* predicting based on a single observation - the value may be completely off)

Comment: I have 380083 records in training data set. Minimum values per distinct type is 26 and max is 8000. These numbers increase from 26 to 8000 uniformly over the distinct values.

Comment: You may want to try to pre-process your data mapping the categorical data into numerical ones. [Here is a technique](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=507538) which converts those into the posterior probability of the target (a classification scenario) or the expected value of the target (a prediction scenario).

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate weight of evidence(WOE) to transform your numeric or categorical variable. Refer to this link http://www.kdnuggets.com/2016/08/include-high-cardinality-attributes-predictive-model.html for understanding WOE.

Answer (score 0):

The best you could do here is that to group the features using what domain knowledge you have. For example phones by brand. If you do not have that information what you could do is that you could group the features by frequency. For example any feature that is not represented more than 5% of the data, you could group as others. You could use both of these methods together as well. For more information please refer [this article](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/11/easy-methods-deal-categorical-variables-predictive-modeling/).

Since logistic regression is distance based model (mostly least squares method) it suffers from the [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality).

Hope this helps though quite late.

thanks

Michael

Answer (score -1):

Typically, dimensionality reduction tasks (such as PCA and FA) are performed in order to decide which features are the most significant.

For example, in the case of PCA which is the most popular and easily employed dimensionality reduction task, significance is defined by largest variation of values.

By performing PCA, you "wash" out variables that are insignificant yet can cause overfitting. I suggestyou familiarize yourself with topics such as PCA, FA and SVD.

Comment: Isn't dimensionality reduction done on the dataset as a whole rather than a single column within the data?

Comment: Yes of course. By first applying PCA, there is a chance that this particular feature is unimportant and you can discard it. If after applying PCA this feature is still significant, then I am afraid that you haven't many options available. The trivial task is to discard values with low cardinality (consider them outliers). Either way, the high cardinality of values will not affect in a negative way your model.